# Bootstrap multiselect is holding the previous value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

I am using a bootstrap multiselect in my application  to show  some data,it is working fine but the problem is that the dropdown is giving result on the basis of supplying an id from the upper dropdown of it,now my problem is that when i first filtering some data by supplying the id from the upper dropdown it is giving result but when i am again doing a filter by supplying another id from the upper one it is holding the previous data and also inclusing the new one.How to get rid of that?? I am giving my code

```
   jQuery.getJSON(url+"&jobId="+jobId+"&type="+type, function(data) { 

         $("#candyListIntAva").append(data.searchResultArray);
         $('#candyListIntAva').multiselect('rebuild');
   });

     $('#candyListIntAva').multiselect({

            includeSelectAllOption: false

        });
```

This is how i am populating the data from backend now how to remove the previous selected data from the list,please help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line will append every new element from the server's reply to the `multiselect` list:

```
$("#candyListIntAva").append(data.searchResultArray);
```

One approach that should work is to empty the `multiselect` list before appending the server's reply to the list:

```
$("#candyListIntAva").empty().append(data.searchResultArray);
```